# how to obtain AKS logs

Tags: azure-aks

A few days ago I had some pods crash and in their logs I don't see anything unusual.

I was using the following command:

kubectl logs mypod -n namespace

How do I see the AKS log to see if I see a problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating your pods using a kubernetes deployment, pods will restart automatically if they crash. The new pod won't have logs for the crashed pod.

To see the logs for the previously terminated pod, add the "-p" argument:

```
kubectl logs -n <namespace> <pod> -p
```